# How to show progress bar with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

Just to tell the user that your request is being processed.

**EDIT**:

I've find myself an image.

[image]
<sub>(source: [maishudi.com](http://maishudi.com/loading.gif))</sub>

How to show it in the center of whole page?

Answer (score 19):

[Progressbar](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar)

[jQuery progressbar](http://blog.dmbcllc.com/2009/05/20/jquery-progressbar/)

[Progress Bars & Controls](http://t.wits.sg/misc/jQueryProgressBar/demo.php)

Comment: 2 links are dead and one is jqueryui

Answer (score 6):

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jQueryProgressBar

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#pb1").progressBar();
$("#pb2").progressBar({ barImage: 'images/progressbg_yellow.gif'} );
$("#pb3").progressBar({ barImage: 'images/progressbg_orange.gif', showText: false} );
$("#pb4").progressBar(65, { showText: false, barImage: 'images/progressbg_red.gif'} );
$(".pb5").progressBar({ max: 2000, textFormat: 'fraction', callback: function(data) { if (data.running_value == data.value) { alert("Callback example: Target reached!"); } }} );
$("#uploadprogressbar").progressBar();
});
```

or

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar

```
$("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 37 });
```

Comment: Hi, is there any plugin to make it a deterministic progress bar, that is, the progress bar will advance proportional to how much of the loading (upload or download) is being done?

Answer (score 3):

You can use one from [Tips for Twits](http://t.wits.sg/jquery-progress-bar/). [Here's a demo](http://t.wits.sg/misc/jQueryProgressBar/demo.php).

Comment: Page has been removed. Getting 404 there.

Answer (score -1):

This tutorial might help you a lot. It will atleast tell you from where to start!

```
 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bYTRKfcG6Rg
```